# Testing if class is copy constructable using libtooling

Tags: c++, clang, libtooling

I would like to use `libtooling` to test whether the defined by a `CXXRecordDecl` is copy constructable.

I have already tried :

- `hasCopyConstructorWithConstParam()`
- `hasTrivialCopyConstructor() || hasNonTrivialCopyConstructor()`

Unfortunately, both of those expressions return `true` if the class's copy constructor is implicitly deleted. This can occur if the class inherits from a non-copyable class or has a member variable that is non-copyable.

The logic to test whether a class is copy constructable is non-trivial and must be exist *somewhere* in `clang`.  **How can I test if a class is copy constructable with `libtooling`?**

Comment: You can retrieve the constructor with `CXXRecordDecl::ctor_begin` and check `CXXConstructorDecl::isDeleted()`...

Comment: @Jarod42 Thanks! That worked - I'll accept this as an answer if you post it as one.

Comment: Also, do you have any explanation of why `hasCopyConstructorWithConstParam` returns `true` even though the class **does not** have a copy constructor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turn comment into answer:

You can retrieve the constructor with `CXXRecordDecl::ctor_begin`

and check `CXXConstructorDecl::isDeleted()`.

Comment: Thanks! Are the default, copy, and move constructors *always* present in the `ctor_begin`/`ctor_end` range? What is the significance of the constructor being marked as (implicitly) deleted versus being entirely absent from the range?

Comment: I tried this, but it did not work. For instance, in code such as `class A{ B b;}`, there will be no copy constructor at all. And you won't know if it's because the class cannot be copied, or because up to now, in the source code, nobody copies the class (is someone copies in instance of the class, then constructors will be generated).